# Magento2 Check Order Was Created by Admin or Customer?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order, magento2.3

I want to check whether an order is created by an Admin or by the customer.

Comment: specify your requirement into detail, what you are looking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, **Magento2** only stores the `remote_ip` in table **`sales_order`** for an order that is place by `customer` (while admin order is set to null).

```
if(!empty($order->getRemoteIp()){
  //place customer
}
else{
  // place by admin
}
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: This not work at all. Follow this example: I am the admin with ip 1.1.1.1, and I create an order on the backend side. The remote_ip field is empty.
I also have a customer account, but my ip is always 1.1.1.1, I create an order on the frontend side. The remote_ip field is empty. 
So this is not a reliable way to determine if the order was created by admin or customer.

Comment: I think, now for all orders remote ip is added if placed from admin also.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php                                                                 
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Orders;                                
class ReadOrders extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action                 
{
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepo
    ) {
    $this->orderRepo = $orderRepo;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $orderPlaced = '';
    $entity_id = '12';
    $order = $this->orderRepo->get($entity_id);
    $orderPlaced = $order->getRemoteIp();
    if ($orderPlaced) {
        echo "Placed by Customer";
    } else {
        echo "Placed by Admin";
    }
}}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Where is this placed?

Answer (score 0):

You can log this with observers. Just use the `sales_order_place_after` event within the `etc/adminhtml` directory inside the `events.xml` to log that an order has been created by an admin. You can do this for every area.
More about areas [Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html).

Example of the events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="My_observer_name" instance="Vendor\NameSpace\Observer\LogOrderAdmin"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

I suggest you create an extra order field via a InstallSchema where you can log this to.

Comment: I will try both ans.