# Magento2-How to check Order Was actual order or Reordered by admin?

Tags: magento2

I want to check whether the order is `Original order` (**Ordered from frontend by customer**) or reordered by admin(in case admin **credit memo** the original order and **reorder** the same order). There is no *relation_parent_id*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento2 Check Order Was Created by Admin or Customer?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264038/magento2-check-order-was-created-by-admin-or-customer)

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar  In this , they are checking remote_ip. But am not suer about remote_ip. is it always empty for admin reorder?

Comment: Yes , it is always empty or you check via store_id if it placed by admin it will be store_id 0 i guess